# Calculating with attributes

Tags: java

Why is the C equal to 0.
What should I do when I want calculate with the modified attributes.
Why the C calculate with the default set up variables and not with the modified ones.

```
public class Object{

        int A;          
        int B;
        int C=A+B;
    
        int AddOnetoA(){
            A=A+1;
            return A;
        }

        int AddOnetoB(){
            B=B+1;
            return B;
        }
    
    
        void ShowA() {
            System.out.println(A);
        }
    
        void ShowB() {
            System.out.println(B);
        }
    
        void ShowC() {
            System.out.println(C);
        }
    }
```

And:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object obj =new Object();
    obj.AddOnetoA();
    obj.AddOnetoA();
    obj.AddOnetoA();
    obj.AddOnetoB();
    obj.AddOnetoB();
    obj.AddOnetoB();
    obj.ShowA();
    obj.ShowB();
    obj.ShowC();
}
```

output:

> 3
>
> 3
>
> 0

Comment: Because when `C` is assigned both `A` and `B` are 0, when do *you* expect `C` to be computed?

Comment: I think this question is relted to [By Reference vs By Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value?r=SearchResults&s=1|1976.6437)

Answer (score 1):

`C` is computed only once. During the time of definition. The `C=A+B` gets executed during class loading time. You are updating `A` & `B` afterwards. So `C` stays as `0`

In other words, the effect of your updates to a variable used in an expression are not retro-actively applied to those expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The default values for integers which are not set is `0`.

You do the following:

```
int A;          // sets A to 0
int B;          // sets B to 0
int C=A+B;      // sets C to A + B = 0 + 0 = 0
```

The notation `C=A+B` doesn't mean that the value `C` will be updated with each update of `A` or `B` but defines only its **initial** value.

You have to update its value with each increment of `A` or `B` variables by yourself:

```
int AddOnetoA(){
    A=A+1;
    c = A + B;      // here
    return A;
}

int AddOnetoB(){
    B=B+1;
    c = A + B;      // and here
    return B;
}
```

---

Don't create an object with the name `Object` which is the one that each one inherits from. Use for example `MyObject` for this simple case.

Lastly, I highly recommend you follow the Java conventions and start the name of variables and methods with a lower-case letter, such as:

```
int addOnetoB(){
    b = b + 1;      // equal to b++;
    c = a + b;      // and here
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want C to reflect always the sum of A+B, you can remove `int C;` and alter `showC`:

```
void ShowC() {
    System.out.println(A+B);
}
```

This is a valid solutions if the effort to calculate C is low.